# Put minified javascript into script tag in HTML directly

Tags: javascript, html, singlepage

I want to put a minified java script contents in  tags directly in HTML page. i have html page like:

```
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="iemagic.js"></script>
      <script src="shim.js"></script>
      <script src="jszip.js"></script>
      <script src="xlsx.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

I have minified all the javascript contents and put it in a single file called "all.js" and the html works fine, now it looks like :

```
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="all.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

I want to include all the content of "all.js" in to HTML directly in "script" tag. I tried with that but no luck, when i open html file in browser it show all the java script content which i have copied in "script" tag.

Is there any other way for this ?

Comment: do you want this to be automated or manual ?

Comment: There are such build tools like [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or [Bower](https://bower.io/) out there. You might want to check them out.

Comment: Thank you all, i too heard that "Gulp and Bower" will do, but i want to know the steps to do that. @Venkatraman - anything, i just want remove all "js" files and there should be only one HTML file.

Comment: Putting all the content – HTML, scripts and CSS – into a single .html file will usually decrease the loading speed of your page. Don't do that.

Comment: @Teemu, Thank you for you suggestion. But i need to know the way.

Comment: @KrupeshKotecha - Thank you for formatting the code.

Comment: " I tried with that but no luck, when i open html file in browser it show all the java script content which i have copied in "script" tag." — Either something is wrong with the way you did that *or* something about the script itself is responsible for that … either way, you need to provide a [MCVE] that **demonstrates the problem**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all for helping me. i have found the solution for this. * added all the "js" files in different "script" tag tested working fine but some of the javascript lines was visible in the browswer. * The problem was "iemagic.js" was having the comments which are not proper and was creating the problem. * I have removed those commented lines and is working find now. without having any "js" file and only one HTML. Thank you All for your help and valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use gulp or [jscompress](https://jscompress.com/)

Comment: i tried this and copied in "all.js", it is working fine. but i want move all the content to HTML page directly in "script" tag. Thank you.

Comment: So you have objects data to that define the content of the page?

Comment: @DincaAdrian - Can you elaborate ? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have scripts and data(articles, products, persons)? compressing files with jscompress will remove the objects and just leave the script it seems...so putting all the data into a JSON file separate will be nice and leave all the logic in all.js. Test Jscompress with document.ready and define a simple object and see what happens.

Comment: @DincaAdrian - I have done this already and it is working. now i want to remove the "all.js" and copy the content of "all.js" in to script tag of the HTML file.